# MicrosoftのWeb版Officeでローカルプリンタにダイレクトに印刷する方法ありますか？

Tags: ms-office

MicrosoftのWeb版Officeを使っているのですが、印刷する際、一旦PDF形式でローカルに保存してからAcrobatReaderで開いて印刷しないといけません。

ローカルプリンタにダイレクトに印刷する方法ありますか？

Comment: これが対象ならば印刷時に選べるのでは？ [Excelの確認・編集もできる無料オンラインサービス「Office Online」とは (1/2)](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1902/14/news026.html) `オンライン版での印刷は、Webブラウザの印刷機能を呼び出している。このため、ローカル環境のプリンタを利用できる。` 違う製品または今は出来なくなっているとかならもう少し詳しい状況を追記してみてください。あるいは企業内のセキュリティ設定で制限している可能性も考えられます。

Answer (score 1):

すいませんでした。そもそも、プリンタのドライバインストールしてませんでした。申し訳ありませんでした。